# What is the proper way to develop a configurable template?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I'm currently developing a web application using Symfony and his template engine, Twig.

As I was trying to implement some forms, I ended up with a template using another reusable and configurable template.

- Here is some simplified code of my form template:

  ```
  {% block global %}
      <div class="modal fade" id="{{ modal_id }}" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <form id="{{ form_id }}" method="post" action="{{ form_action }}" class="form_ajout_groupe">
                  <!-- Form/Modal content ...  -->
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          var {{ namespace }} = {
              var1 : [],
              var2 : [],
          }

          $("#{{ form_id }} input[name='...']").val(...);
      </script>
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- And here is how it's included:

  ```
  {% use '@Bundle/modalForm.html.twig' with global as modalForm_global %}

  {% set form_id = "formAjoutGroupe" %}
  {% set modal_id = "modalAjoutGroupe" %}
  {% set namespace = "addForm" %}
  {{ block('addGroup_global') }}
  ```

What concerns me is that although I've been able to develop a well-functionning page with this structure, It feels like an "hacky" way of using Twig.

I would like to know if there are better ways to create a configurable template.

I'm also unsure on how to manage my JS with Twig, as in my case it ends up being a bit of a mess to have each templates with his own JS inside.
What are the best practices on this matter?